# Wix - File is locked for delete after opening its database

Tags: c#, database, view, wix, windows-installer

I have some problems while trying using WindowsInstaller library or Wix Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.
I'm, getting exception that the file being used by the process and I cannot delete it even though I've closed all record,view and database and disposed them.

```
try
{
   string currentDir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
   string msiPath = "PathTo\MyMSI.msi";

   using (InstallPackage installPackage = new InstallPackage(msiPath, DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly))
   {
       string query = "SELECT * FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion'";
        using (View view = installPackage.OpenView(query))
        {
            view.Execute();
            using (Record record = view.Fetch())
            {
               string version = record.GetString(2);
               Console.WriteLine(version);
               record.Close();
            }

            view.Close();
         }

         installPackage.Close();
    }

    File.Delete(msiPath);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

And still I get the following:

> Access to the path 'PathTo\MyMSI.msi' is denied.

I've also tried with the object

> Database

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Everything seems to be in order.  What version of WiX are you using?

Comment: @Christopher Painter Hi Thanks for the reply. I'm using Wix 3.8. I believe its the latest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure out what is blocking the delete action.
It appears that the file was in **read only**.
I don't know why I got this kind of exception but the following solved it:

```
//removing read only from file in order to interact with it
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(msiPath);
 if (fileInfo.IsReadOnly)
 {
   fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
 }
```

Hope it will help others.

I appreciate everyone who helped here for your time.

Comment: That crossed my mind as you were properly disposing all your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Below are some steps you could follow for ur problem :

1. Wait a minute and try deleting the file again, sometimes Windows or the program using the  file may still be closing and therefore still using the file you're attempting to delete.
2. Close and Explorer window and re-open.
3. Locate the program using the file and close it. If you're uncertain what program is using the file, close all programs until you're able to delete the file.
4. Try using unlocker, a free software program designed to unlock any file being used by Windows or other programs without restarting the computer.
5. Reboot the computer. If after closing all programs you're still unable to delete the file, it's likely that something in the background is still using the file.
6. If after rebooting the computer you're still unable to delete the file, boot the computer into Safe Mode and delete the file.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks I tried what you suggested but it did not work. I've figured out what was the problem. Best Regards.

Comment: This seems an answer more targeted for SuperUser then the problem at hand.